# ATS error kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error in iOS 9 even with domain exception set in info.plist

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ios9

I can't seem to either get my ssl domain exception for amazon s3 configured correctly.  Also - why is there an ssl error with amazon s3?  Shouldn't it be a valid ssl request?  I've lowered the minium TLS requirment and even tried without the https but it looks like the key is not being matched with my request.

```
let stringUrl = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/icon.png"
    if let
        url = NSURL(string: stringUrl),
        data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url), // error (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
        image = UIImage(data: data)
    {
       return image
    }
```

My info plist

```
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <key>s3.amazonaws.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had nested the plist keys incorrectly , the domain key goes in the dict, not above it.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> 
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>s3.amazonaws.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>  
                <true/>  
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```